# Acentuation in php, showing latin symbols

Tags: string, html-parsing, html-helper, non-ascii-characters

I'm writing a program to parse html data from a portuguese website, thing is, when I echo the data I read I get those weird symbols:

```
                                        Meu PC estragou e tenho um netbook que u
so para assuntos acadΩmicos. Que raiva, nπo roda nem CS aqui. Aff que raiva! Com
o pode?  Jß coloquei todas as mais baixar configuraτ⌡es e nao roda!
```

the original text is:

```
                                        Meu PC estragou e tenho um netbook que u
so para assuntos acadêmicos. Que raiva, não roda nem CS aqui. Aff que raiva! Com
o pode?  Já coloquei todas as mais baixar configurações e nao roda!
```

notice the acentuation:

> acadêmicos -> acadΩmicos
>
> Já -> Jß

how do I fix this ? I already tried:

```
echo utf8_decode($assunto);
```

but it didn't work ! help!

Answer (score 0):

Set the encoding in the header.

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Then to make sure the browser uses UTF-8 meta tag in the HTML head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's a console aplication, I run it from the console, and that didn't work, do you have any idea ? thanks anyways

Comment: Which console are you using, is it normally able to print those characters?